# Visual Studio.NET 2010 debugging - how to stop execution when any Response.Redirect is hit

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In my solution (partly c#, partly VB.NET), I am suspecting that somewhere during the execution there is a Response.Redirect that I am unaware of that destroys my page context.

There are currently 218 Response.Redirects in my code. I have set breakpoints to the usual suspects, but I'd prefer a way to tell Visual Studio to stop whenever a line with Response.Redirect is hit. Is there a way? Or an alternate debugging practise?

A more generic version of that question would be: is there a way to add breakpoints to a solution through a Find action, similar to the "Bookmark All" button? Or to "convert" bookmarks to breakpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the cleanest way would be to refactor the redirect functionality into a helper, and add your logging/debugging there where there's a single point.

If you just want something quick, you could turn on Exceptions in the debugging menu, and there should be a thread abort exception that you can break on.

Comment: I'll go with the break on the Thread Abort Exception. It's not a 100% thing, but works well enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In Visual Studio, go to *Debug/New BreakPoint/Break at Function...*. Type in `System.Web.Response.Redirect`.

Now the debugger will break whenever Redirect is called.

If you want a specific overload of `Redirect`, you can add the parameters, e.g., System.Web.Response.Redirect(string)`. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15d1wtaf%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I get a warning in the Breakpoints window when doing this: `the function could not be found`. Also, the breakpoint never gets hit.

Comment: System.Web needs to be referenced in your project.